# How to find matching names between two table and update first table in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data sets:

**1.[all_users] User Names, in Pandas DF:**

```
id | name         | gender
---------------------------
 1 | Mark jackson | unknown
 2 | Sara Coheorn | unknown
 3 | susan boyle  | unknown
.
.
```

**2.[gender] Name-Gender Index, in a List of Tuples:**

```
[('Jake', 'male'),
 ('susan', 'female'),
 ('khalid', 'male'),
 ('mark', 'male'),
 ('james', 'male')]
```

How can I search & update first *Data_set* (all users) from the information in Name-Gender Index (By updating gender column)? Knowing that I'll have to check `if name in gender *is in* name in all_users`, not only `equals`; because user names are sometimes full names, first name, nickname or numbers.

Not sure how to tackle this?

> I tried doing nested for loop, but it didn't work:
>
> ````py
> for i, user in all_users.iterrows():
>     for gender in gender:
>         if gender[0] in str(all_users.name[i]):
>             all_users.gender[i] = gender[1]
>             break
>         else:
>             break ```
> ````

^This always produce errors

Comment: What should happen if in `all_users` is name, for example 'Susan Mark` and in `gender` Susan is Female and Mark is Male?

Comment: I filtered with Regex to take only first part as name. (Space separated) but the first part might be numbers or nick name.. but at least gender will be more accurate if there's an actual first name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue, it was in referencing `all_users` index, i was calling with `i` which is the auto index, not the id i have in the table. Using `all_users.at[i, 'name']` and `all_users.at[i,'gender']` worked well. With few enhancements.

This worked:

```py
for i, user in all_users.iterrows():
    for gender in gen:
        try:
            if gender[0] in str(all_users.at[i, 'name']):
                all_users.at[i,'gender'] = gender[1]
                break
        except TypeError:
            break
```